# ajax pagination in rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Below you will see my jquery:

```
$(function() {
$(".pagination span.page a").click(function (){
    $.get(this.href, null, alert("The pagination link was clicked" + this.href), "script");
    return false;
});


});
```

I know my call on my classes are working because the alert pops up. I think that it is where I am calling "script" where it is failing because it is not pulling up the page. This is a Rails 3 application that is calling an index.js.erb script. Here is the index.js.erb:

```
$("#search").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("search")) %>");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does the server output say?  does it render your template?  What is the response from the server from the browser's debugging tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking on how rails calls ajax I came across a post. It said to do the following:

```
def index
  format.js
end
```

Once I called this it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to render a partial?

```
$("#search").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "search") %>");
```

Comment: I am trying to render a partial but with rails 3 you can do a render with (render "search"). Just to make sure putting my render the way you have it didn't work either.

Comment: Whats the output of your server log?  What does the network panel in your browser's debugger show for the response?